# Implementing CI/CD pipeline in bitbucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, bitbucket, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, bitbucket-pipelines

I am trying to implement CI/CD pipeline in bitbucket for the project. Basically whenever new code will pushed to the branch 'XamDev', I want to deploy the web api on aws elastic beanstalk using bitbucket CI/CD.

Below is the bitbucket-pipelines.yml for the same where I have configured all aws settings. This file I have added in Visual studio solution.

```
# This is a sample build configuration for .NET Core.
# Check our guides at https://confluence.atlassian.com/x/5Q4SMw for more examples.
# Only use spaces to indent your .yml configuration.
# -----
# You can specify a custom docker image from Docker Hub as your build environment.
image: microsoft/dotnet:sdk

pipelines:
  default:
    script:
          - echo "This script runs on all branches that don't have any specific pipeline assigned in 'branches'."
  branches:
    XamDev:
    - step:
        caches:
          - dotnetcore
        script: # Modify the comma`nds below to build your repository.
          - pipe: atlassian/aws-elasticbeanstalk-deploy:0.5.4
            variables:
              AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: '<Access_Key>'
              AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: '<Secret_Key>'
              AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: 'us-east-1'
              APPLICATION_NAME: '<ApplicationName>' // elastic beanstalk application name provided 
              ENVIRONMENT_NAME: '<EnvironmentName>' // elastic beanstalk environment provided
              ZIP_FILE: 'myfile.zip'
              # S3_BUCKET: '<string>' # Optional.
              # VERSION_LABEL: '<string>' # Optional.
              # DESCRIPTION: '<string>' # Optional.
              # WAIT: '<boolean>' # Optional.
              # WAIT_INTERVAL: '<integer>' # Optional.
              # COMMAND: '<string>' # Optional.
              # DEBUG: '<boolean>' # Optional.
```

So, after committing the code, I am not seeing any pipeline is running from bitbucket nor the aws deployment using elastic beanstalk is started.

When I checked my bitbucket account and branch it doesn't show any pipeline is configured. I am using VS 2019 with .net core web api.

Any help on this appreciated !

Comment: Have you enabled pipelines in your admin screen on bitbucket?

Comment: Yes, it is already enabled, Repository=>Settings => Pipelines => Setting=> Enable Pipelines